# ImportError: cannot import name build_time_vars

Tags: python, python-2.7

i get the error message above if i run the command 'python' from terminal.

```
ImportError: cannot import name build_time_vars.
```

Do you have any idea or solution?

The full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 563, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 545, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 272, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 247, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 237, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 582, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 528, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 412, in _init_posix
    from _sysconfigdata import build_time_vars
ImportError: cannot import name build_time_vars
```

and the output of `python -v`:

```
# installing zipimport hook
import zipimport # builtin
# installed zipimport hook
# /usr/lib/python2.7/site.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/site.py
import site # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/site.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/os.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/os.py
import os # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/os.pyc
import errno # builtin
import posix # builtin
# /usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py
import posixpath # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/stat.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/stat.py
import stat # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/stat.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/genericpath.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py
import genericpath # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/genericpath.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/warnings.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/warnings.py
import warnings # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/warnings.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/linecache.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/linecache.py
import linecache # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/linecache.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/types.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/types.py
import types # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/types.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py
import UserDict # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.py
import _abcoll # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/abc.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/abc.py
import abc # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/abc.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.py
import _weakrefset # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.pyc
import _weakref # builtin
# /usr/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py
import copy_reg # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/traceback.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/traceback.py
import traceback # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/traceback.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py
import sysconfig # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/re.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/re.py
import re # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/re.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py
import sre_compile # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.pyc
import _sre # builtin
# /usr/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.py
import sre_parse # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.py
import sre_constants # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.py
import _sysconfigdata # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata_nd.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata_nd.py
import _sysconfigdata_nd # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata_nd.pyc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 563, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 545, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 272, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 247, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 237, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 582, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 528, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 412, in _init_posix
    from _sysconfigdata import build_time_vars
ImportError: cannot import name build_time_vars
# clear __builtin__._
# clear sys.path
# clear sys.argv
# clear sys.ps1
# clear sys.ps2
# clear sys.exitfunc
# clear sys.exc_type
# clear sys.exc_value
# clear sys.exc_traceback
# clear sys.last_type
# clear sys.last_value
# clear sys.last_traceback
# clear sys.path_hooks
# clear sys.path_importer_cache
# clear sys.meta_path
# clear sys.flags
# clear sys.float_info
# restore sys.stdin
# restore sys.stdout
# restore sys.stderr
# cleanup __main__
# cleanup[1] sysconfig
# cleanup[1] abc
# cleanup[1] _weakrefset
# cleanup[1] sre_constants
# cleanup[1] re
# cleanup[1] _warnings
# cleanup[1] zipimport
# cleanup[1] _sysconfigdata
# cleanup[1] _sysconfigdata_nd
# cleanup[1] signal
# cleanup[1] traceback
# cleanup[1] posix
# cleanup[1] exceptions
# cleanup[1] _weakref
# cleanup[1] sre_compile
# cleanup[1] _sre
# cleanup[1] sre_parse
# cleanup[2] copy_reg
# cleanup[2] posixpath
# cleanup[2] errno
# cleanup[2] _abcoll
# cleanup[2] types
# cleanup[2] genericpath
# cleanup[2] stat
# cleanup[2] warnings
# cleanup[2] UserDict
# cleanup[2] os.path
# cleanup[2] linecache
# cleanup[2] os
# cleanup sys
# cleanup __builtin__
# cleanup ints: 18 unfreed ints
# cleanup floats
```

Comment: Always include the *full traceback*. Is this an import from `_sysconfigdata`?

Comment: Is this on Ubuntu, by any chance?

Comment: Next step then; what are the contents of the file `/usr/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata_nd.py`? This *should* start with something like `# system configuration generated and used by the sysconfig module` and a dictionary named `build_time_vars`, but apparently that is missing for you.

Comment: It probably will come down to you having to re-install your debian `python2.7-minimal` package to repair whatever damage has been done here though.

Comment: Does this happen all the time, no matter what directory you run python from? I've seen similar errors when names of python modules or packages in my working directory clashed with names of modules/packages from the standard library.